# Calculate the frequency of n dice with m faces + how to order elements in tuples. Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dice

I am a complete beginner and this is my first question to the community.

I am learning loops and I am trying to create a program in Python that allows me to calculate the frequency of the sums that can result from the roll of n dice with m faces. The variables **n** and **m** should be input by the user. I know you must have seen this problem many times but I couldn't find a proper answer to my solution, probably because of the way I structured my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
sums = []
frequency = []
probability = []
lst = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of dice: "))
m = int(input("Enter the number of faces in the dice: "))
lst = list(range(m + 1)[1:])
print(lst)
for item in (lst):
  for x in (lst):
    sums.append(item+x)
counter = len(sums)
for item in (sums):
  frequency.append(sums.count(item))
for item in frequency:
  probability.append(item/counter)
probability = ['%.3f' % elem for elem in probability]
results = np.column_stack((sums, probability))
new_results = [tuple(row) for row in results]
uniques = np.unique(new_results, axis=0)
print(uniques)
```

and this is the outcome (as you can see, it works only with 2 dice at the moment):

```
[['10' '0.083']
 ['11' '0.056']
 ['12' '0.028']
 ['2' '0.028']
 ['3' '0.056']
 ['4' '0.083']
 ['5' '0.111']
 ['6' '0.139']
 ['7' '0.167']
 ['8' '0.139']
 ['9' '0.111']]
```

I am stuck in the following two problems :

1. I am struggling to understand how to repeat the loop for n dice. I think the way I designed the program has made things difficult in this sense. Could you please help?
2. How can I order the output in the proper way? I would like results to come out as follows:

```
[['2' '0.028']
 ['3' '0.056']
 ['4' '0.083']
 ['5' '0.111']
 ['6' '0.139']
 ['7' '0.167']
 ['8' '0.139']
 ['9' '0.111']
 ['10' '0.083']
 ['11' '0.056']
 ['12' '0.028']]
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me to solve these problems. Also, any suggestion to improve my code will be great! 
Thank you,
Marco

Comment: for the second point, try sorting the array (using the first element of each list as the key) and then printing it out

Answer (score 0):

1: Theoretically you'd add more dice by nesting more loops in lines 11 and 12. But since that's not possible in runtime to my knowledge, I'd use a recursive approach:

```
def alloutcomes(mylist, sides, throwsleft):
  if throwsleft == 0:
    return mylist
  else:
    newlist = []
    for x in mylist:
      for i in range(1, sides+1):
        newlist.append(x+i)
    return alloutcomes(newlist, sides, throwsleft-1)
```

Then `sums = alloutcomes([0], m, n)` is the list you're looking for. If you go through this code with a piece of paper, mimicking every step, you'll quickly understand how it works. With this list you'll be able to continue normally

2: To sort a list of non integer variables, you can use `sorted()` together with a key().
You'll first have to define a "key" function that allocates every element you put into it a integer. In your case you'd just return the first element of each tuple. sorted(list, key) will then check the key of every element in the list and return a list that is sorted accordingly.